# Trying to create list from two lists

Tags: c#, linq

Below is my class:

```
public class Test
    {
        public int TestId { get; set; }
        public List<VariantsRank> VariantsRanks { get; set; }
    }

    public class VariantsRank
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Rank { get; set; }
    }
```

Below are 2 methods:

```
var testList = CreateDataFromList();//return  List<Test>
Var testListfromDb = GetDatafromDB();//return  List<Test>
```

Records of testList:

```
[0] : 100
      List of VariantRanks

[1]: 101
      List of VariantRanks
```

Records of testListfromDb:

```
[0] : 100
      List of VariantRanks // Order of variants will be different here and that is important to me

[1]: 101
     List of VariantRanks  // Order of variants will be different here and that is important to me
```

Below is my variable in which I want final output:

```
var final = new List<Test>();
```

**Scenarios :**

**1**)

```
testList = 100 and 101
testListfromDb = 101

Expected Output for 1st scenario : final = 100 and 101(2 records and this 101 record will be from testListfromDb)
```

**2**)

```
    testList = 100 and 101
    testListfromDb = 100

   Expected Output for 2nd scenario : final = 100 and 101(2 records and this 100 record will be from testListfromDb)
```

**3**)

```
 testList = 100 and 101
    testListfromDb = 100 and 101

    Expected Output for 3rd scenario : final = 100 and 101 (2 records and both will be from testListfromDb)
```

I have done 3rd scenario but I am not getting how to solve 1st and 2nd scenario.

**Code :**

```
var final = new List<Test>();
var testList = CreateDataFromList(list); //return  List<Test>
Var testListfromDb = GetDatafromDB();//return  List<Test>
    if (testListfromDb == null)
           final = testList;
    else
       {
          if (testList.Count == testListfromDb.Count) // 3rd scenario
              final = testListfromDb;

       }
```

**Update**:

```
 public void Method()
        {
            var testList = new List<Test>();
            testList.Add(new Test { TestId = 100 });
            testList.Add(new Test { TestId = 101 });
            var testListfromDb = new List<Test>();
            var final = new List<Test>();

            //scenario 1
            testListfromDb.Add(new Test { TestId = 101 });
            //expected output in final variable
            final[0] = testList[0];
            final[1] = testListfromDb[0];

            //scenario 2
            testListfromDb.Add(new Test { TestId = 100 });
            //expected output in final variable
            final[0] = testListfromDb[0];
            final[1] = testList[1];

            //scenario 3
            testListfromDb.Add(new Test { TestId = 100 });
            testListfromDb.Add(new Test { TestId = 101 });
            //expected output in final variable
            final[0] = testListfromDb[0];
            final[1] = testListfromDb[1];
        }
```

Comment: If you have two lists, first compare the sizes of the list, make the largest list the final list. Then loop through the second list adding items that are not already in the final list?

Comment: I assume that was you who upvoted that non-answer?

Comment: Downvoter please give the reason for downvoting as it would help me and others for not commiting mistake again while asking question :)

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: @StephenMuecke :No i havent upvoted that answer but i would like to upvote it although it doesnt solve my problem but i still appreciate the efforts towards helping me :)

Comment: @Enigmativity :What wrong did you find in this question.i didnt explained my question well or i didnt show my efforts like what i have tried.It will be more helpfull for me if you can specify exact reason of downvoting.Thanks :)

Comment: You should also provide your input data as valid C# code and then explain what the output should be for those inputs. We can then copy-paste your code to be able to provide you an answer easily. Right now it's a lot of work to answer this question. You should do most of the work to make it easy for us and obvious for future readers.

Comment: @Learning, Its not clear what you want the results to be and what you mean by things like _final = 100 and 101(2 records and this 101 record will be from testListfromDb)_ Give us an example of the data that your returning and what the output should be

Comment: @Enigmativity :Ok got it sir.I appreciate your advice and i will keep this in mind while asking question again.Thanks :)

Comment: @Learning - Please edit this question.

Comment: @Learning - Thanks for the update. Can I ask what the point of `VariantsRank` is? It's not in your data. Also, the three scenarios you've put forward are all in the one method, but I assume you mean that each of the scenarios is run independently of the others?

Comment: The logic is still not quite clear. Are you saying that if `testListfromDb` contains a `TestID` that matches one of the `TestID` values in `testList`, then use that result rather than the one from `testList`. And what happens of `testList` contained 100 and 101, but `testListfromDb` contains 100 and 102 - would the result be 100, 101 and 102 (where 100 was from `testListfromDb`)?

Comment: @Enigmativity Most important thing is VariantsRank 
which contains order for each of the variants.This order are stored in my database for each of the test so if i get this VariantsRank order from database in my testListfromDb then i will use data from testListfromDb for that testId but if i dont have variantsorder for testid then i will use variantsorder from testList

Comment: @Learning - Do I understand that that means `VariantsRank` is irrelevant for your query here?

Comment: @StephenMuecke :yes you are right about your first point and this case will never gonna come testList have 100 and 101 and testListfromdb will have 101 and 102.testList will always contains more testId records

Comment: @Enigmativity :Actually it is important but here matching will be done on testId that is why i have not shown variantsorder records but in my final variable i would like to have variantsList

Comment: @Learning, Thats is just a matter of looping through `testListfromdb` and check if each items `TestID` exists in `testList`, and if so, overwrite the `VariantsRanks` property with the value from the item

Comment: @Learning - You've made this question hard to understand by introducing unnecessary code. You need to provide a [mcve]. The word "minimal" is important here.

Comment: @Enigmativity :Ok i understand my mistake and i will make sure i dont commit this mistake next time.Actually i try my best to ask good question but sometimes i fail badly

Comment: The answer by @Enigmativity is cool, but to put it another way which you might find easier to understand - `foreach (var item in testListfromDb) { var match = testList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TestID == item.x.TestID); if (match != null) { match.VariantsRanks = item.match.VariantsRanks; }}`

Comment: @StephenMuecke:Thank you so much for the answer.You always help me.Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think solves your problem:

```
public List<Test> Process(List<Test> testList, List<Test> testListfromDb)
{
    return 
        testListfromDb
            .Concat(testList)
            .GroupBy(x => x.TestId)
            .SelectMany(x => x.Take(1))
            .ToList();
}
```

If you change `Test` to this definition:

```
public class Test
{
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
}
```

Then this code can test the results:

```
var scenario1 = Process(new List<Test>()
{
    new Test { TestId = 100, Source = "Test" },
    new Test { TestId = 101, Source = "Test" }
}, new List<Test>()
{
    new Test { TestId = 101, Source = "DB" }
});
```

[image: scenario 1]

```
var scenario2 = Process(new List<Test>()
{
    new Test { TestId = 100, Source = "Test" },
    new Test { TestId = 101, Source = "Test" }
}, new List<Test>()
{
    new Test { TestId = 100, Source = "DB" }
});
```

[image: scenario 2]

```
var scenario3 = Process(new List<Test>()
{
    new Test { TestId = 100, Source = "Test" },
    new Test { TestId = 101, Source = "Test" }
}, new List<Test>()
{
    new Test { TestId = 100, Source = "DB" },
    new Test { TestId = 101, Source = "DB" }
});
```

[image: scenario 3]

Comment: Ok upvoted your answer for your kind efforts towards helping me but 1 thing i dont understand is  why you have use Take(1) ??

Comment: The `.Take(1)` removes the duplicate ID when there is a record in both the database and the test list with the same `TestId`.